# Is brushing your teeth in the public toilet a culture specific activity?

Tags: health, factoids, culture, hygiene

I have seen on a number of occasions in Australia of people brushing their teeth in a public toilet, whether it is in a library or office building. I am trying to work out whether this is something that is common to a particular culture or if there are some reasons that I don't know about (since it doesn't seem to be that common), even though I have generally only seen Asians do this.

The question I would like to know is whether it is an acceptable practice for western people to do this in an Eastern country (and vice versa), because I find it not particularly a good thing to do personally, and I want to know if this is an issue in a cross-cultural situation.

Comment: I've also seen European people do this...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not specifically about travelling.

Comment: Of course it's about traveling. You _already_ know the answer for your _home_ culture. The question is, how to behave when you travel to others. Having said that, the question would be better if it were specific to one country or region. The question is on-topic but a bit open-ended.

Comment: Agreed. Until the question is about a region he's travelling to, it's not specific enough.

Comment: How do you know people do it in the toilet? I can imagine people doing in a restroom at a sink with running water? Possibly if they're doing it actually in the cubicle is to save time and kill two birds with one stone. I often brush my teeth in the shower for this reason.

Answer (score 6):

Some people brush their teeth after every meal ([even though they probably shouldn't](http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/05/21/really-never-brush-your-teeth-immediately-after-a-meal/)), and if you're at work or out and about, a public toilet is pretty much the only sensible place to do this.  I'm not aware of anything particularly cultural related to this.